# Dbeaver 7.0.4 No suitable driver found for jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jdbc, dbeaver, amazon-athena

I have recently updated DBeaver from 7.0.4 to 22.0.1 and encountered this issue. I have tried to add SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.0.27.1001.zip into its library path but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It works after I pointed it to AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar
AthenaJDBC42.jar breaks my driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just need to use this driver AthenaJDBC42.jar. 4.1 is not required.